# I want to create a rest service with spring that accepts json as paramters

Tags: json, spring, rest

I want to create a service using spring rest services that accepts json as parameters.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setAppData/{appId}/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void setAppData(@PathVariable String appId,
                       @RequestParam Category appCategory,
                       @RequestParam AppMetadata appMetaData) {
}
```

I want that the client will send the appCategory and the appMetadata as json and spring (or an interceptor that I will write) will convert it to an object.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setAppData/{appId}/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void setAppData(@PathVariable String appId,
                       @RequestBody AppData appData) {
}
```

**POJO**

```
public class AppData {
    private Category appCategory;
    private AppMetadata appMetaData;

    //getters/setters
}
```

The client then sends `AppData` as JSON. You need Jackson to be available on the CLASSPATH.

Old but valuable reference: http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/